# Add characters to a character array c++

Tags: c++, pointers

Can someone tell me what's wrong with the following?

I'm trying to add characters to a character array. name is a pointer to a character array in the MyString class.

```
void MyString::add_chars(char* c)
{
        if(l < strlen(c)+strlen(name))
                name = resize(name, l, sizeof(c));
        int i,j;
        for(i=0; i<strlen(c); i++) {
                name[i+l-1] = c[i];
                l++;
        }
}

char* MyString::resize(char* vptr, int currentsize, int extra) {
        char* temp = new char[currentsize + extra];
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < currentsize; i++) {
                temp[i] = vptr[i];
        }
        vptr = temp;
        return vptr;
}
```

And in main:

```
 MyString g ("and");
 g.add_chars("baasdf");
 cout << g.get_name() << "\n";
```

But get_name returns "andb". How can I fix my code?

**Edit:**
Updated code, still same result..

```
void StringList::add_chars(char* c)
{
        char* my_new_string = resize(name, l, sizeof(char));
        if( my_new_string != NULL )
        {
                delete [] name;
                name = my_new_string;
        }
        int i,j;
        for(i=0; i<strlen(c); i++) {
                name[i+l-1] = c[i];
                l++;
        }
        name[l-1] = '\0';
}

char* StringList::resize(char* vptr, int currentsize, int extra) {
        char* temp = new char[currentsize + extra + 1];
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < currentsize; i++) {
                temp[i] = vptr[i];
        }
        vptr = temp;
        return vptr;
}
```

Comment: wow, that's a lot of errors.  Did you try stepping through it in a debugger and watching the variables and parameters?  That is _always_ the first step of debugging.  Not asking us.

Answer (score 1):

This line is wrong:

```
 name = resize(name, l, sizeof(c));
```

You should not take the `sizeof(char*)`, which your `c` variable is, but you should do `sizeof(char)` or just 1.

Also, make sure that you do +1 on the size to take care of the zero termination `char` at the end of your string.

Comment: There's other very relevant errors too, `MyString::resize` alters a local parameter, and never releases any memory.

Comment: Why would it be sizeof(char)? I'm adding more than one character

Comment: it should actually be `sizeof(n*char)` where `n` is the amount of chars you're adding

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was trying to accomplish with sizeof(c).. Can you tell me what the correct replacement would be? I'm trying to find n

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, am I right in assuming that this is a learning exercise for you in learning "how to create your own string class"?    C++ has already got a built-in *string* type which you should always prefer for the most part.

the `sizeof` operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which in this case is **c** whose type is `char*` - it looks like what you're actually after is the length of a null-terminated character array (a "C" string") - you're already using *strlen*, so I'd suggest you simply want to use that again.   (taking a null-terminator into account too)

```
name = resize(name, l, strlen(c) + 1);
```

Note, that your code looks as if it suffers from memory leaks.   You're assigning a new value to your *name* variable without clearing up whatever existed there first.

```
if(l < strlen(c)+strlen(name))
{
    char* my_new_string = resize(name, l, strlen(c));
    if( my_new_string != NULL )
    {
        delete [] name;
        name = my_new_string;
    }
}
```

*EDIT*: As other replies have pointed out, there's still plenty wrong with the code which could be resolved using C++'s `string` and `vector`.

Here's one possible way you could implement add_chars

```
void MyString::add_chars(char* c)
{
    if( c != NULL && name != NULL )
    {
        size_t newlength = strlen(c) + strlen(name) + 1;
        char* newstring = new char[newlength];

        if( newstring != NULL )
        {
            size_t namelength = strlen(name);
            size_t remaining = newlength - namelength;

            strncpy( newstring, name, newlength );
            strncpy( &newstring[namelength] , c, remaining );

            delete [] name;
            name = newstring;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You got the half that Tony missed, but missed the parts he has.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I fix my code?

Don't fix it. Throw it away and use `vector<char>` or just `string`.

> But I insist, how can I fix my code!?

OK, OK, here is how...

1. Get a nice debugger, for example [this one](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-cpp-express).
2. Step carefully through the code, constantly inspecting the variables and comparing them with what you expect them to be.
3. When you reach the call to `resize`, take note of `sizeof(c)` (assigned to `extra` parameter of `resize`). When you realize it is not what you expected, ask yourself:  what is the *purpose* of `sizeof`, and you'll understand why.

BTW, you also have a memory leak and a very poor performance due all these `strlen`s.

Comment: Dear downvoter, did I miss something important of made a grievous error? I don't mind being downvoted, but I'd like to understand why, so I can _learn_.